# How could I enter third string to List<Map<String, String>> on Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary

```
  List<Map<String, String>> splashData = [
        {"text": "EGZERSİZİNİ SEÇ", "image": "assets/logo/Splash1.png"},
        {"text": "TELEFONUNU SABİTLE", "image": "assets/logo/Splash2.png"},
       {"text": "UYARI", "image": "assets/logo/Splash3.png"}
    ];
```

I'am trying to add 3 Strings to List in Flutter. How could I third string to my List?

Example I want to make

```
   List<Map<String, String, String> splashData :[
           {"text": "EGZERSİZİNİ SEÇ", "image": "assets/logo/Splash1.png","text1": "EGZERSİZİNİ SEÇ"},
           {"text": "TELEFONUNU SABİTLE", "image": "assets/logo/Splash2.png","text1":"EGZERSİZİNİ SEÇ"},
          {"text": "UYARI", "image": "assets/logo/Splash3.png","text1": "EGZERSİZİNİ SEÇ"}];
```

Is this possible to add?

Thanks for respond.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a key with a value just like that.

```
for(final Map<String, String> data in splashData){
  data['text1'] = 'EGZERSİZİNİ SEÇ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
splashData.forEach( (data) => data['text1'] = "EGZERSİZİNİ SEÇ"));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.